# How to concisely express the idea that one value of several in a set can make the values of all others moot.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I've been trying to find a way to write this all day. I've learned a lot of math in the process, but still haven't found anything especially concise.

I'm trying to express the idea that if you have some bunches of things, and each of those things can be assigned a value, that one bunch could have the highest value if one of its things were assigned a sufficiently high value.

e.g. Imagine 3 bundles of 10 infinitely large gas tanks. One bundle could have more than the other two, even if all of its gas tanks had very little gas, except for one which had a huge amount of gas.

I think the idea is simple, is there a way it can be concisely expressed in notation?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just saying that sums can be large even if only one term is large. So if $a_1,\dots,a_{10}$ is the first bundle and $b_1,\dots,b_{10}$ is the second, etc., then you are saying that $\Sigma a_i\geq \Sigma b_i$ even though $a_i < b_j$ for most i and j.

Without words:
$|\{(i,j)|a_i<b_j\}|> |\{(i,j)|a_i>b_j\}|\nRightarrow\Sigma a_i< \Sigma b_i$

Comment: Yes, that's it. Is there any way to express that idea without the words used between "So if a1... for most i and j"?

Comment: @Hal is my new edit more what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, just going to try and read it now -but yeah, that'll do it.

Comment: What do the '|'s mean?

Comment: I would read the whole thing out loud as "the statement'the set of all i,j such that ai is less than bj has greater size than the set of all I,j such that ai is greater than bj' does not imply the statement 'the sum if the ai is less than the sum of the bj"

Comment: The | sign in the braces means "such that". The || around the braces means "cardinality" or "size".

Comment: Okay, and going to the gas-tank example - what would the lower case a and b correspond to? How about the lower case i and j, and subscript i and j?

Comment: a corresponds to the first bundle, b to the second, and c would be a third bundle. The i is any number from 1 to 10 representing the first tank, second tank, etc. And j is the same thing as i

Comment: btw, there is a great example that answers your title, though not your specific question (so irrelevant, I guess).  It's the problem of using a bag of coins to get a fair 50/50 outcome with only the knowledge that one coin, and you know not which, is actually fair.  Flip all and count parity!

Comment: @BrianRushton I thought more about this last this morning. I wondered whether we need to use both i and j; do we? As I interpreted the expression, 'a' is a variable for any element of set A, and the subscript 'i' represents that the set A is indexed by I, which enumerates each of those elements - making it clear we are talking about multiple elements (if we had just written 'a', that could have represented any one element from A). The '(i,...)|(ai...' says that the set you are building between { } contains some elements of I, such that (continued)

Comment: @BrianRushton ... such that those elements are the elements of I that have been indexed to the elements of A (i.e. it has been made clear that we are talking about Tank1 in Bundle A, Tank2 in Bundle A... and so on) then we further specify that we want only those tanks in Bundle A that have less fuel in them then then any tank in Bundle B... Hmm. I think I may have, just now, seen why they're necessary. It seems that we couldn't have that set include tanks from both bundles without enumerating them separately - because it would express a contradiction

Comment: contradiction was the wrong term - and even then, I think I was mistaken about the reason why i and j are needed. To me it still seems that you could write (i)|ai<bi and get all of the tanks in A that have less fuel than any tank in B and all of the tanks in B that have more fuel than any tank in A. Hmm - but then, I suppose that would produce a set of references to tanks that does not tell you anything about the bundle those tanks were from. Whereas, if you use 'i' just for tanks in A, and 'j' just for tanks in B, then you retain that information. Is that the reason you used both 'i' and 'j'?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing (I assume) with positive values only, setting an object in set $A$ to a value greater than the maximum total value of the elements in all other sets $X$, will make the values of the values of the other elements in $A$ irrelevant.

Say that $f$ assigns a positive (non-negative) value to each object. We can say that the values of $a_i\in A$ ($i\neq j$) don't matter when there is a $j$ such that
$$
f(a_j)\geq \max_{\mbox{all sets $X$}}\left\{\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\right\}
$$

Comment: Okay, so today, I just touched on the notation you used. Let me see if I interpreted it correctly: You're saying, in "ai E A(i/=j)", that the elements in set A are denoted 'a' and they are indexed (shown via subscript i), and that i and j do not reference the same elements (i /= j). The 'f(aj) >= means that the function assigns a value to aj such that it is greater than or equal to... (cont)

Comment: ... the greatest of (max) the elements in all other sets (all sets X). As for the smaller notes around the sigma, the xEX means that anything denoted by x is an element of X, the sigma is to sum them, but I don't get the f(x).  How did I do with the rest of it?

Comment: the left-hand-side is ok. On the RHS, you take the sum of the values assigned the elements in every set $X$, so $f(a_j)$ is at least the sum of the values in $X$, not at least the max value of one of them.

Comment: Okay I get it. Basically the 'f(x)' stands for the function assigning a quantity that represents the amount in each tank (to use the example) to each element of the set X. Whereas, on the LHS, f(aj) references the value assigned to an element in A, such that it is greater than the sum of those in X. But then, why the 'max all sets X'?

Comment: Suppose there is a set of tanks with amounts $(1,1,1,1)$ and one with $(1,2,3,4)$ and a set $A=(a_1,a_2)$. If $a_1=4=1+1+1+1$, it isn't always true that $a_1+a_2\geq 1+2+3+4$, so you must have $a_1\geq \max\{1+1+1+1,1+2+3+4\}$.